# FPDF: Format one element from an array

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using the Labels code for FPDF.  I am getting the contents of label from an array generated by a sql call to a database.  It works fine for me.  I would like to format one of the lines differently from the others, either larger font or bold.  Here is the code I am using:

```
require('PDF_Label.php');

// Standard format
$pdf = new PDF_Label('5160');

$pdf->AddPage();

require('includes/mysqli_connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT FullLegalName, CivicAddress1, CivicCity, CivicPostal FROM coops";
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

if($result){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $name = $row['FullLegalName'];
    $address = $row['CivicAddress1'];
    $pcode = $row['CivicPostal'];

    //each s relates to the inserts.  Watch for double quotes around variables
    $text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s %s\n%s", "$name", "$address", 'Toronto', 'ON', "$pcode");
    $pdf->Add_Label($text);

}

$pdf->Output();
```

I would like to make $name either bold or a larger font, both if possible.

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Weird, "Add_Label" is not in the documentation for FPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php

Comment: Add label is function that is in PDF_Label.php, which seems to extend FPDF

Answer (score 1):

Different print formats can be achieved by adding 2 functions to the `PDF_Label.php` class:

```
// Return XY co-ordinates for additional text (different $pdf->SetFont)
function LabelX() {
    $_PosX = $this->_Margin_Left + $this->_COUNTX*($this->_Width+$this->_X_Space) + $this->_Padding;
    return ($_PosX);
}
function LabelY() {
    $_PosY = $this->_Margin_Top + $this->_COUNTY*($this->_Height+$this->_Y_Space) + $this->_Padding;
    return ($_PosY);
}
```

This establishes the co-ordinates of the current label.

An example script (part of a loop):

```
$pdf->SetFont(Arial,B,12);  // Bold (font size as defined for label type).
$addresstext = sprintf("%s %s %s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", "$title", "$initials", "$surname", "$address1", "$address2", "$town", "$county", "$postcode", "$country");
$pdf->Add_Label($addresstext);
// Add secondary text in normal smaller font.
$LabelX = $pdf->LabelX();
$LabelY = $pdf->LabelY();
$pdf->SetXY($LabelX,$LabelY);
$pdf->SetFont(Arial,'',9);
$secondtext = sprintf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n%s  %s  %s", "$reminder", "$memberno", "$postalarea");
$pdf->MultiCell(95,7, $secondtext,0,'R');  // Prints bottom right of label.
```

Probably not as neat as it could be, but it works!